# Função onScroll em JS

Tags: javascript

Estou colocando esse código em um script separado do *HTML*, mas ele não funciona 100%. Quando crio a tag `<scrip></script>` dentro do *HTML* ele funciona, alguém sabe me explicar o motivo?

arquivo `.js`

```js
scrollFunction = function () {
var navbar = document.getElementById("myNavbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 600px)")

   if (x.matches) { 
    
        if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
            navbar.classList.add("sticky")
        } else if (window.pageYOffset < sticky){
            navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
        }  
    } else {
     
        if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
            navbar.classList.add("sticky")
        } else if (window.pageYOffset < sticky) {
            navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
        }  
    }
};
```

O mesmo acontece com esse código a baixo que fica no meu `onClick`.

```html
tstar = function() {
var sticky;
  var x = document.getElementById("myNavbar");
  if (x.className === "navbar sticky") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  }else if (x.className === "navbar sticky responsive") {
    x.className = "navbar sticky";
  }
  else if (x.className === "navbar"){
    x.className += " responsive";
  } 
  else {
    x.className = "navbar";
  }
};
```

Comment: Vc está indexando esse .JS dentro do `<head>` do seu documento? Ou está colocando lá no final do documento depois de todo o código, mas logo antes da tag de fechamento do `</body>`?

Comment: Estou sim! Ele pega outros scripts, só não tá lendo esses dois que citei :(
<script src="http://agropecuariasertaneja.com.br/assets/js/script.js"></script>

Comment: Vc escreveu sua tag de Script exatamente assim? Se foi está faltando o http:// ou https:// no caminho do seu arquivo... O ideal é que os .JS venham sempre no final do documento, logo antes do fechamento do body

Comment: o problema não está aí, como disse tem outros scripts funcionando! Desculpe, o stack retirou o http rsrs mas ele tá correto no html!